# DrawElements not working as expected with multiple objects

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

In my program I basically put all objects in one buffer, and now I am having issues when I want to draw multiple objects, if I only draw one it still works.
The issues started to occur when I roughly changed all `glDrawArrays` to `glDrawElements` calls, and of course all underlying infrastructure.
As of now I simply made a *one-to-one* mapping from vertices to indices.

I am using Java 8, LWJGL and OpenGL 3.3.

Initialization:

```
//drawable vertex buffer
vertexBuffer = new StaticDrawArrayBuffer().create().bind().fillData(Drawable.putAllVertexData(drawables));
vertexArray = new VertexArrayObject().create().bind()
        .setAttribute(vertexBuffer, VS_POSITION, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
        .enableAttributes(VS_POSITION);

//drawable elements buffer
elementBuffer = new StaticDrawElementArrayBuffer().create().bind().fillData(Drawable.putAllElementsData(drawables));
```

So I do the following:

1. Create an `ARRAY_BUFFER` and store all vertex data in there.
2. Create a Vertex Array Object, and set where the `position` data can be found.
3. Create an `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and store all indices in there.

With contents as follows;

Vertex Data:

```
-400.0
0.0
-400.0
-400.0
0.0
400.0
400.0
0.0
-400.0
-400.0
0.0
400.0
400.0
0.0
-400.0
400.0
0.0
400.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
-1.0
1.0
1.0
-1.0
```

Indices data:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
```

So that is 126 float, that should get mapped by `(x, y, z)` to 42 indices.

However when I do the following calls subsequently:

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
gl.glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 6)
```

The objects get drawn all mixed through each other, definately not how they are supposed to look, what I thought the code would do is;

- Take vertex data corresponding to the first 6 indices after offset 0 and draw.
- Take vertex data corresponding to the first 36 indices after offset 6 and draw.

What could be possible reasons that this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glDrawElements last parameter used to be a pointer to the index array. With VBOs this parameter gets reused as a byte sized offset into the VBO. So it does not take an index, but a byte offset into the VBO to where the data starts. In your case that would be `sizeof(GLfloat) * x` where `sizeof(GLfloat)` usually is 4. So you have to multiply your particular data layout you have to multiply the offset index by 4 to get the byte offset.

Comment: It seems to be like it needs to be `sizeof(GL_float) * x`, and not the extra `* 3`, could that be correct aswell?

Comment: @skiwi: Yes, I was accidently thinking about offsets into VBOs, while of course using the size parameter of glVertexAttribPointer you already have that information there.